# Can I use an IF statement within my SQL Server query to use a query on multiple SQL versions?

Tags: sql-server

I am deploying a stored procedure that checks the backup age of every server I support. However, with a little of programming experience that I have, I know I can add or delete part of my code with an IF statement that checks the versions it runs on.

Here's the code :

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    SUBSTRING(s.name,1,50) AS 'DATABASE Name',
    b.backup_start_date AS 'Full DB Backup Status',
    c.backup_start_date AS 'Differential DB Backup Status',
    d.backup_start_date AS 'Transaction Log Backup Status',
    DATEDIFF(HOUR, b.backup_start_date, GETDATE()) AS 'Age Full Backup',
    --Get number hours since last full backup
    ISNULL(DATEDIFF(HOUR, c.backup_start_date, GETDATE()), 0) AS 'Age Diff Backup',
    --Get number hours since last diff backup
    ISNULL(DATEDIFF(HOUR, d.backup_start_date, GETDATE()), 0) AS 'Age Tlog Backup',
    --Get number hours since last tlog backup
    s2.state_desc AS 'Status',
    s2.recovery_model
FROM 
    MASTER..sysdatabases s 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    msdb..backupset b ON s.name = b.database_name 
                      AND b.backup_start_date = (SELECT MAX(backup_start_date) AS 'Full DB Backup Status'
                                                 FROM msdb..backupset
                                                 WHERE database_name = b.database_name
                                                   AND TYPE = 'D') -- full database backups only, not log backups
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    master.sys.databases s2 ON s2.name = b.database_name
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    msdb..backupset c ON s.name = c.database_name 
                      AND c.backup_start_date = (SELECT MAX(backup_start_date) 'Differential DB Backup Status'
                                                 FROM msdb..backupset
                                                 WHERE database_name = c.database_name 
                                                   AND TYPE = 'I')
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    msdb..backupset d ON s.name = d.database_name 
                      AND d.backup_start_date = (SELECT MAX(backup_start_date) 'Transaction Log Backup Status'
                                                 FROM msdb..backupset
                                                 WHERE database_name = d.database_name  
                                                   AND TYPE = 'L')
WHERE 
    s.name != 'tempdb' 
    AND s.name NOT IN ('master', 'model', 'msdb') 
    AND s.name NOT LIKE '%TMP[_]%'
```

I was wondering if I can add this part to the WHERE clause at the very end :

```
    AND dbid NOT IN (SELECT database_id
                     FROM master.sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states AS DRS
                     INNER JOIN sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states AS ARS ON ARS.replica_id = DRS.replica_id
                     WHERE ARS.is_local = 1 AND role_desc = 'SECONDARY')
```

but only for SQL Server higher or equals to 2012? Since AlwaysOn was introduced in 2012, this code generates an error on 2008 R2 and lower.

So far, I have this IF statement that checks the version which works pretty well :

```
IF CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(@@VERSION, 22, 4)) >= 2012
    PRINT 'true'
ELSE
    PRINT 'false'
```

I know that I can just delete the code and create my Stored Procedure, but I want to know if it's possible to place an IF statement like we can do in C# or even in JavaScript to adjust our code from the versions it runs on.

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't want that clause in your SQL, depending on the version of your SQL Server, you would need to use Dynamic SQL. You can't have part of your statement not run based on the environment of the server.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the idea of using a Dynamic SQL, @Larnu?

Comment: As @Larnu express, you need to this in a dynamic SQL.

Comment: Or create two procedures, one for each version of the query. Then create a third procedure that decides which of the other procedures to call based on the version currently being examined.

Comment: @Thomas, I made some research about Dynamic SQL. I am not quite sure how this works, since I am a Junior DBA. Is this website explains it correctly? [link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/)

Comment: @Kyl12 Yes, you can use that link as inspiration too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it something like this:

```
DECLARE @Version int

SET @Version = (select CONVERT(int,substring(@@Version,22,4)))

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @WHERECLAUSE nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @SQLNESTED nvarchar(max)

SET @SQL = 'SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(s.name,1,50) AS [DATABASE Name]
    ,   b.backup_start_date AS [Full DB Backup Status]
    ,   c.backup_start_date AS [Differential DB Backup Status]
    ,   d.backup_start_date AS [Transaction Log Backup Status]
    ,   DATEDIFF(HOUR, b.backup_start_date,GETDATE()) AS [Age Full Backup]    --Get number hours since last full backup
    ,   isnull(DATEDIFF(HOUR, c.backup_start_date,GETDATE()),0) AS [Age Diff Backup]    --Get number hours since last diff backup
    ,   isnull(DATEDIFF(HOUR, d.backup_start_date,GETDATE()),0) AS [Age Tlog Backup]    --Get number hours since last tlog backup
    ,   s2.state_desc AS   [Status]
    ,   s2.recovery_model
FROM MASTER..sysdatabases s 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        msdb..backupset b ON s.name = b.database_name 
        AND b.backup_start_date =(
            SELECT MAX(backup_start_date) AS [Full DB Backup Status]
            FROM msdb..backupset
            WHERE database_name = b.database_name
            AND TYPE = ''D'') -- full database backups only, not log backups
    LEFT OUTER JOIN master.sys.databases s2 ON s2.name=b.database_name
    LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb..backupset c ON s.name = c.database_name AND c.backup_start_date = (
        SELECT MAX(backup_start_date) as [Differential DB Backup Status]
        FROM msdb..backupset
        WHERE database_name = c.database_name AND TYPE = ''I'')
    LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb..backupset d ON s.name = d.database_name AND d.backup_start_date = (
        SELECT MAX(backup_start_date) as [Transaction Log Backup Status]
        FROM msdb..backupset
        WHERE database_name = d.database_name AND TYPE = ''L'')
WHERE s.name != ''tempdb'' AND s.name NOT IN(''master'',''model'',''msdb'') AND s.name NOT LIKE ''%TMP[_]%'''

SET @WHERECLAUSE = 'AND dbid NOT IN (
    SELECT database_id
    FROM master.sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states AS DRS
        INNER JOIN sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states AS ARS
        ON ARS.replica_id = DRS.replica_id
    WHERE ARS.is_local = 1 AND role_desc = ''SECONDARY'')'


IF(@Version >= 2012)
BEGIN
SET @SQLNESTED  = @SQL + ' '+  @WHERECLAUSE

exec (@SQLNESTED)
--PRINT @SQLNESTED
END

ELSE
BEGIN
SET @SQLNESTED = @SQL

exec (@SQLNESTED)
--PRINT @SQLNESTED
END
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll consider Dynamic SQL from now on.

Answer (score 0):

To explain what my point was, this is one method of achieve what you're after:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
SET @SQL = N'
SELECT DISTINCT
       SUBSTRING(s.name, 1, 50) AS ''DATABASE Name'',
       b.backup_start_date AS ''Full DB Backup Status'',
       c.backup_start_date AS ''Differential DB Backup Status'',
       d.backup_start_date AS ''Transaction Log Backup Status'',
       DATEDIFF(HOUR, b.backup_start_date, GETDATE()) AS ''Age Full Backup'',            --Get number hours since last full backup
       ISNULL(DATEDIFF(HOUR, c.backup_start_date, GETDATE()), 0) AS ''Age Diff Backup'', --Get number hours since last diff backup
       ISNULL(DATEDIFF(HOUR, d.backup_start_date, GETDATE()), 0) AS ''Age Tlog Backup'', --Get number hours since last tlog backup
       s2.state_desc AS ''Status'',
       s2.recovery_model
FROM master..sysdatabases s
     LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb..backupset b ON s.name = b.database_name
                                      AND b.backup_start_date = (SELECT MAX(backup_start_date) AS ''Full DB Backup Status''
                                                                 FROM msdb..backupset
                                                                 WHERE database_name = b.database_name
                                                                   AND type = ''D'') -- full database backups only, not log backups
     LEFT OUTER JOIN master.sys.databases s2 ON s2.name = b.database_name
     LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb..backupset c ON s.name = c.database_name
                                      AND c.backup_start_date = (SELECT MAX(backup_start_date) ''Differential DB Backup Status''
                                                                 FROM msdb..backupset
                                                                 WHERE database_name = c.database_name
                                                                   AND type = ''I'')
     LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb..backupset d ON s.name = d.database_name
                                      AND d.backup_start_date = (SELECT MAX(backup_start_date) ''Transaction Log Backup Status''
                                                                 FROM msdb..backupset
                                                                 WHERE database_name = d.database_name
                                                                   AND type = ''L'')
WHERE s.name != ''tempdb''
  AND s.name NOT IN (''master'', ''model'', ''msdb'')
  AND s.name NOT LIKE ''%TMP[_]%''';

IF CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(@@VERSION, 22, 4)) >= 2012 BEGIN
    SET @SQL = N'
  AND dbid NOT IN (SELECT database_id
                   FROM master.sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states AS DRS
                        INNER JOIN sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states AS ARS ON ARS.replica_id = DRS.replica_id
                   WHERE ARS.is_local = 1
                     AND role_desc = ''SECONDARY'')';
END

SET @SQL = @SQL + N';';
PRINT @SQL; --Your debugging best friend
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```